# Automatically Configuring Settings for New Xcode Projects

Tags: xcode

When I create a new Xcode project, I have to go in by hand and tweak a number of different settings in various places.  For example:

- In Build Settings, have the compiler treat warnings as errors.
- In Breakpoint Navigator, set a breakpoint for all exceptions.
- In Schemes, enable zombie checking.

Is there a way to automate setting these various Xcode settings?  I think I'd like to have some sort of script (be it shell, Python or AppleScript) that I run on a new project to modify the settings, but I'm certainly open to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For build/project settings you can use xcconfig files to do this for each target.  Once you've created your xcconfig file, you can use the variable names that are visible in the build settings.

Unfortunately I don't think you can use that to modify breakpoints and Schemes.

Answer (score 0):

Amongst those choices, I think Python is the best way to go. Xcode 4 broke a lot of AppleScript support and AppleScript has too many problems if you want non-frustrating development.

The three20 project includes some Python scripts that modify Xcode projects. That might give you something to work with. http://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/src/scripts